# Configure JOGL with maven

Tags: maven, jogl

I'm trying to configure JOGL with maven following the guide found here:
http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Maven

As far as I understand should be enough to include these dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jogamp.gluegen</groupId>
      <artifactId>gluegen-rt-main</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jogamp.jogl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jogl-all-main</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Because they say:

```
"So, when you add a dependency on jogl-all-main in your own project, the native jar files of jogl-all are brought in as transitive dependencies and everything works as expected."
```

I have create a Maven project including those dependencies and now the project looks like this:
[image]

I wrote a simple HelloWorld class to test it:

```
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLCapabilities;

    public class HelloWorld {
        public static void main (String args[]) {
            try {


                System.loadLibrary("jogl");
                System.out.println("Hello World! (The native libraries are installed.)");
                GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(null);
                System.out.println("Hello JOGL! (The jar appears to be available.)");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

But running it I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jogl in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
    at jogl.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:12)
```

So it seems the native dll (I'm on windows) are not found.

What is wrong here?
Is the tutorial wrong, or did I miss something?

This is the pom.xml I'm using:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>jogl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jogl</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jogamp.gluegen</groupId>
            <artifactId>gluegen-rt-main</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jogamp.jogl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jogl-all-main</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:
I was following the new procedure but using the old code to load the libraries.
Indeed with the new libraries you don't need to use this line anymore:

```
 System.loadLibrary("jogl");
```

I have test it with this Line class and it works...

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.jogamp.opengl.GL2;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLEventListener;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;

public class Line implements GLEventListener{
   @Override
   public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
      final com.jogamp.opengl.GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
      gl.glBegin (GL2.GL_LINES);//static field
      gl.glVertex3f(0.50f,-0.50f,0);
      gl.glVertex3f(-0.50f,0.50f,0);
      gl.glEnd();
   }
   @Override
   public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
      //method body
   }

   @Override
   public void init(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
      // method body
   }
   @Override
   public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
      // method body
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      //getting the capabilities object of GL2 profile
      final GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);
      GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities(profile);
      // The canvas 
      final GLCanvas glcanvas = new GLCanvas(capabilities);
      Line l = new Line();
      glcanvas.addGLEventListener(l);
      glcanvas.setSize(400, 400);
      //creating frame
      final JFrame frame = new JFrame ("straight Line");
      //adding canvas to frame
      frame.getContentPane().add(glcanvas);
      frame.setSize(frame.getContentPane().getPreferredSize());
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }//end of main
}//end of classimport javax.media.opengl.GL2;
```

Comment: This code wasn't necessary with JOGL 1 neither, I advise you to read the JOGL user's guide. When the library path was correctly set, JOGL 1 was able to load its native libraries for you. JOGL 2 introduced the automated native library loading; when it works, you don't have to set the library path as long as the JARs containing the native libraries are in the classpath. By the way, I advise you to switch to JOGL 2.3.2, I remember that something was missing in the JARs pushed into Maven Central in a previous minor version, don't waste any time with any bug that we have already fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. About the code "System.loadLibrary("jogl");" I was following the book : "Learning Java Bindings for OpenGL" it's from 2004, it seems meanwhile the specifications have changed a lot...

Comment: It was already wrong in 2004. In my humble opinion, the book "Computer Graphics Programming in OpenGL with Java" by V. Scott Gordon and John L. Clevenger is far better. If you have any question very specific to JOGL, rather ask them on our forum, only a very few maintainers come on StackOverflow, we can't be everywhere.

Comment: I will have a look to the book you suggested. Thank you. When you say "our forum" you are referring to this one: http://jogamp.org/forum.html , right?

Comment: Yes, exactly, this is the official JogAmp forum: http://forum.jogamp.org